# is it possible to pass percentDiscount as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had this:

```
var percentDiscount;

function calculate(sale, original) {

percentDiscount = Math.round(eval(((original-sale)/original) * 100));

    return percentDiscount;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

var salecost;
var originalcost;
var percent;
$('.product').each(function() {

    salecost = $(this).find('.price').html();
    salecost = salecost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");


    originalcost = $(this).find('.actualprice').html();
    if(originalcost == null) return;
    originalcost = originalcost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");

    percentDiscount = calculate(salecost, originalcost);

   if (69 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 101) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 70% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge70');
    }

    else if (49 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 70) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 50% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge50');
    }

    else if (29 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 50) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 30% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
    }


    else if (19 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 30) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 20% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
    }


});
});
```

Is it possible to pass `percentDiscount` so that I could sort the discount on the page? for the example, sort by % discount: [all] [20%] [30%] [50%] [70%] and then match the calculation of each item to be displayed by discount?

If it is possible, please give me example on how it should be coded or sorted? I searched for possible answer on this but no avail. all I saw most is xxx.sort() but it wouldn't work for percentage discount...

Another question - I wanted to know how to sort by link applying to the url to match the percentage discount as well. Then how to skip the items that are not on sale?

Comment: you'll have to be more clear on your second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try like this :

```
// create an array of dom elements - this assumes a structure like :
// <div class='myStuff'>
//   <span class='product'></span>
//   <span class='product'></span>
// </div>
// and the spans get sorted inside the .myStuff div

var products = [];
$(".product").each(function(){
  products.push(this);
});

products.sort(function(left,right){
  //get left percentDiscount
  //get right percentDiscount

  if(leftDiscount < rightDiscount)
     return -1;
  if(leftDiscount > rightDiscount)
     return 1;
  return 0;
});

// then clear the original .products from .myStuff div and re-add them from the products array.
```

For //get left percent :

```
salecost = $(left).find('.price').html();
salecost = salecost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");


originalcost = $(left).find('.actualprice').html();
if(originalcost == null) return;
originalcost = originalcost.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");

percentDiscount = calculate(salecost, originalcost);
```

and the same for the right - these are just html elements.

Comment: wait i am a little confused. How do we get left percentDiscount or right percentDiscount? Did you refer to the if statement above?